# On button click, div not hiding as expected with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this (I am calling jQuery the following way because I am doing this in Wordpress):

```
jQuery('.wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contactFormPhone').hide(); 
});
```

The button code:

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
```

The div I want to hide:

```
<div class="contactFormPhone">(877) 888-8888</div>
```

I would expect when the button is clicked, that the div called 'contactFormPhone' would be hidden, but nothing happens.

Comment: are you sure you have references to jquery lib ? Cause it does what you want, see : http://jsfiddle.net/z42T5/

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: are you waiting for DOM to be ready? And prevent default behaviour too if FORM is submited

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? Do you call this code after jQuery has been loaded=

Comment: Is the button added to the page dynamically? ```on``` might be what you want, if it is.

Comment: Make sure that your script is either after the HTML it acts on or wrapped in document.ready.

Comment: You have to wait for the elements to finish loading. If they are static, then wait for the DOM to finish loading, and if they are dinamically added then wait for the responsible function to finish before attempting to execute your JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've referenced the correct jQuery file with the correct path as well as wrapping your code inside DOM ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
        jQuery('.contactFormPhone').hide(); 
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that will solve your problem.

```
  jQuery('.wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
    jQuery('.contactFormPhone').hide(); 
});
```

Checkout the working fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/f4jvS/1/

Comment: Did what you asked for. Ran a demo on fiddle and did it. As fas as I can see I just used your code and pointed out that it runs fine.

Comment: Posting the same code and saying it works fine is not an answer.

Comment: Just trying to help. I don't think its a valid reason to down vote this answer.